# unrecognized import path (import path does not begin with hostname)

Tags: go

I've installed go as per the custom installation clause of [the installation instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.9.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz), as I have installed to a user directory, in order to accommodate having multiple versions of go.

When I `go get .` from my go project's src directory, I get the error message type already mentioned above ―

> unrecognized import path (import path does not begin with hostname)

Can you please explain, why does go look for a hostname and how that should possibly be avoided in a typical project?

As an aside, the problem was originally encountered by me in setting up the [following specific project and hash](https://github.com/habeanf/yap/tree/9bd0606a7be454631bc8700fffe10a06c813963c), which the accepted answer still refers to.

Comment: What is the unrecognized import path? Can you provide the full error output?

Comment: Right, sorry: `package yap/app: unrecognized import path "yap/app" (import path does not begin with hostname)`

Comment: Why are you trying to do go get on a local package. Please read the documentation of got get.

Comment: That means "yap/app" isn't found, and you can't get it because it doesn't start with a hostname. Your local sources need to be in GOPATH. (and you probably _should not_ be setting GOROOT)

Comment: Wow, that project is terrible - their import paths are objectively wrong. Where they import `yap/app`, they should be importing `github.com/habeanf/yap/app`, etc. The only fix would be to clone the GitHub repo into `$GOPATH/src/yap` manually and then try to build it.

Comment: Okay, I guess the project doesn't use standard clean way. @Adrian your suggestion indeed works. I'll learn more about go project structure and imports as I go, and PR to fix the build instructions of the specific project to at least include your instruction. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you - reposted as an answer. Sorry you got so many downvotes... the Go community on SO has largely tired of an endless stream of GOPATH/GOROOT/go get questions that boil down to simple user error, but that was not the case here. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I was expecting some :-))) but I think that when no answer explains why things work the way they do, a new and better one should ask for it. I re-edited the question to be more generic too. Again many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`go get` downloads dependencies and packages by assuming that the import path (in the `import` statements in source code) identifies a URL where the package can be downloaded, e.g. github.com/habeanf/yap. It works so long as developers use imports correctly; unfortunately, the developer of the yap project did not.

Where they import `yap/app`, they should be importing `github.com/habeanf/yap/app`, etc. The only fix would be to clone the GitHub repo into `$GOPATH/src/yap` manually and then try to build it. You might want to open a GitHub issue on that project and request that they fix the import paths so it can be built like a normal Go project.

Comment: Ok. So if I have a mix of imports, some refering local 'code modules'( eg. /home/mylib1) and some refering to 'upstream modules'(eg. github.com/myself/mylib2), go get will fail because it tries to download the local  'code modules' using its local path as an absolute remote url?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with setting up the same project on windows (note: updated project documentation is [here](https://nlp.biu.ac.il/%7Ertsarfaty/onlp/hebrew/documentation)).

Turns out GOPATH was set up for my username by GO installation while I updated the system environment GOPATH according to this description from the docs:

> Set $GOPATH environment variable to your workspace: export
> GOPATH=path/to/yapproj

Removing GOPATH for my username solved the problem and I managed to build the application.

I'm posting this to prevent others from spending too much time on this issue as I did.