# "package _/home/vitaly: unrecognized import path "_/home/vitaly" (import path does not begin with hostname)"

Tags: go, installation

Running `go get -u` returns:

```
package _/home/vitaly: unrecognized import path "_/home/vitaly" (import path does not begin with hostname)
```

I tried to reinstall `golang` - nothing changed.

`/home/vitaly` is my $HOME.

Output of `go env`:

```
GOARCH="386"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/vitaly/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/vitaly/.gopath"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.10"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.10/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GO386="387"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m32 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build014652388=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with all updates, 386 system (32 bits).

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: @mkopriva I see this document now, looks like I understand this, but why I see this strange error when trying to update installed packages?

Comment: Post a [mcve].  Show the directory structure if your files and the line of code that produces the error.

Comment: Can you give you `go env` output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unrecognized import path (import path does not begin with hostname)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187280/unrecognized-import-path-import-path-does-not-begin-with-hostname)

Comment: @CeriseLimón I removed  `~/.gopath` and installed only `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session` - but this the same error.

Comment: @Adrian added to the question.

Comment: @mkopriva I checked this question - I think this this is not a duplicate - I trying to update all packages (`go get -u` from any directory), not to install some library for local project.

Comment: Are you running `go get -u` from your home directory?

Comment: @CeriseLimón yes, hm I found that if I change directory to `foo` I will get `package _/home/vitaly/foo: unrecognized import path "_/home/vitaly/foo" (import path does not begin with hostname)
`.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich That important information is missing from the question.  Run `go help packages`  for information on how specify packages to the `go get` and other commands.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, again my inattention: in order to update all packages we need to run `go get -u all`.